# Graph Execution Error in colab how to solve?

Tags: google-colaboratory

---

NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 2>()
1 # Make predictions on the custom data
----> 2 custom_preds = loaded_full_model.predict(custom_data)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
50   try:
51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

NotFoundError: Graph execution error: